# Open google map with particular motion mode Android Intent

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

Hi I am trying to open google map direction using default intent and i pass motion mode walking but it open default driving how can i open map with particular motion mode

**My Code**

```
    uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + sLatitude + "," + sLongitude + "&daddr=" + dLatitude + ","+ dLongitude + "&mode=walking";

    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
    intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
    startActivity(intent);
```

[Google map url for testing](http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=23.0336451,72.524168&daddr=22.3038945,70.80215989999999&mode=walking)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should google `directions api` instead of normal link.

The direction link is:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/output?parameters`

It has the parameter of `mode`, which you can change to `walking`, and then use the intent.

For more details, please refer [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#TravelModes).

Comment: HI can you provide url for my url  : "https://www.google.com/maps?saddr=23.0336451,72.524168&daddr=22.3038945,70.80215989999999&mode=walking"

Comment: My requirement is open Google map with intent with particular motion mode

Comment: Actually I compared lot of url for default and walking. It seems no rules for this. Do you find out something?